# How does celery achieve at most once delivery with redis backend?

Tags: redis, celery

Using Celery with brokers like RabbitMQ does give us the at most once or exactly once delivery. as you know, pubsub mechanism of redis broadcasts messages to all subscribers, so all workers will receive the jobs, but I've seen that only one of them executes it. how is this achieved?

Comment: It's an open-source project... You can find the answer in the code (kombu / celery).

Comment: @DejanLekic duh

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful. If Redis crashes while a task is still queued, it will probably be forgotten.